# SQL Selecting Chained Records

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull data that is chained by the event of an order number. Please refer to below for a sample table of data. Note the orderno does increase for each new order created.

Table "History":

```
|part|orderno|transaction|transaction_date|
  A    12345    Removal      2015-01-01
  A             Install      2015-01-05
  A    123456   Removal      2015-02-01
  A             Install      2015-02-09
  A    1234567  Removal      2015-03-01
```

How the report should look:

```
|removal_orderno|trans_date|next_removal_orderno|
   12345         2015-01-01      123456
   123456        2015-02-01      1234567
```

Note* there are no keys that link the Removals to Installs. The removals and installs follow the same pattern. You will not be able to remove a part without it first being installed.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I actually have no idea how to start this. I am trying to google as much as I can but have no luck currently. Any ideas where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: Start with: "select * from History order by transaction_date, orderno" ... then, add / subtract / alter until you get close and can ask a more specific question

Answer (score 1):

```
     SELECT h.orderno,
     (SELECT TOP 1 orderno 
     FROM history i 
     WHERE i.partno=@partno and i.serialno=@serialno and transaction in ('Removal') and trans_date and i.orderno>h.orderno
     ORDER BY del_date) AS 'Next Removal Orderno'
     FROM history h
```